# Is there a way to condense multiple conditional statements with Javascript destructuring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements

I'm building a simple React app that lets the user provide three types of feedback (good, neutral, and bad). If no type of feedback exists yet, it will render the "no feedback given" message, and once any type of feedback has been given, it will show the stats for it.

I've managed to accomplish this with the existing conditional shown below, but I was wondering if I can condense the three "or" statements, perhaps through a destructuring technique

Edit for clarity: the data for the feedback values is being stored in three separate pieces of state in the parent component.

```
return (
    <>
      <h1>Statistics</h1>

      {(good > 0 || (neutral > 0) || bad > 0)? 
        <p>{feedback}</p> :
        <p>No feedback given</p>}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you could add them into an array and use `.any` to check if any of them are `> 0` e.g. `[good, neutral, bad].any(feedback => feedback > 0)` which should return `true` or `false`

Comment: You mention destructuring; do you have an object with these properties? If so, add it to the question

Comment: A lot of this has to do with your data. Where and how is it being stored? Could you store it differently to be able to do things like this more effectively?


Based on what you've shared, I honestly like what you have. I'm a big fan of human friendly code and yours reads very nicely

Comment: @George, maybe you meant `Array.prototype.some()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))?

Comment: you might be over engineering something that should rather be simple

Comment: You can shorten it without creating unnecessary arrays or objects, if you really want: `{  ((good || neutral || bad) && <p>{feedback}</p>) || <p>No feedback given</p> }`

Comment: Another way can be : { good + neutral + bad > 0 ? <p>{feedback}</p> : <p>No feedback given</p> }

Comment: I don't get what this has to do with destructuing.

Comment: @secan Don't abuse `&&`+`||` when you mean to use the conditional operator.

Comment: Can you show us how you are constructing the `feedback`, please? Maybe that's null/empty anyway when there is no feedback, and you should use *that* in the condition.

Comment: @secan Yeah that's what I meant I must have been tired but then again `any` seems a better name than `some` don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

why not just do a simple string comparison , if user has feed back set feedback to that feedback if not set it to NO_FEEDBACK

```
return (
    <>
      <h1>Statistics</h1>
      {feedback != "NO_FEEDBACK"
        ?<p>{feedback}</p>
        :<p>No feedback given</p>}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've managed to accomplish this with the existing conditional shown below, but I was wondering if I can condense the three "or" statements

No, not really. It's only three of them, and you don't have a list of them, so there's not much to gain. Your current code is quite concise already - all you can do is omit the superfluous parenthesis:

```
<>
  <h1>Statistics</h1>

  { good > 0 || neutral > 0 || bad > 0 ? 
    <p>{feedback}</p> :
    <p>No feedback given</p>}
</>
```

If the values are known to only be non-negative numbers (i.e. only `0` or `> 0`), you can also omit the `> 0` comparison and just go by the truthiness of the values:

```
<>
  <h1>Statistics</h1>

  { good || neutral || bad ? 
    <p>{feedback}</p> :
    <p>No feedback given</p>}
</>
```